# What do you call someone who balances work and personal life well?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

> **[Work–life balance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work%E2%80%93life_balance)** is a concept including proper prioritizing between "work" (career and ambition) and "lifestyle" (health, pleasure, leisure, family and spiritual development/meditation).
>
> Related, though broader, terms include "lifestyle calm balance" and "lifestyle choices".

So what would you call someone who has a well-balanced work and life (personal life)?

Note: **"Well-balanced"** may fit but it has a broader sense and has other connotations as well. A single-word noun would be preferable but can be an adjective too.

Comment: Stable, happy, settled ?

Comment: or a player...lol

Comment: A good juggler.

Comment: settled seems like a good answer but there might be a better one.

Comment: Single word? Well, there goes, [*squared away*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/squared+away) and [*got their shit together*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/got+their+shit+together).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eudaemonia

[(also eudemonia) a contented state of being happy and healthy and prosperous;a feeling of wellbeing and happiness (from GK.eu-, good + daimon, spirit)](http://eudaemonie.com/html/eudaemonie.htm)

Comment: Aha! A Eudaemoniac!

Comment: Living a 'juste milieu' sounds less dramatic!

Comment: +1 Eudaemonia and Eudaemoniac! New words for me. But I will wait for some other answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

A person with **[life in perspective](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=life+in+perspective)**.

It is usually by having a broader perspective that such people understand why and when to give each part of life it's due attention. Balance is good, in moderation.

Comment: I think this is usually used as "to put life in perspective". Is it more like to be settled?

Comment: I don't think so. Balance is dynamic, responding to changes. To be settled implies stability and little to no change.